# When open a modal on page load but modal open two times

Tags: angularjs

I want to develop a angularjs web application where I need when url has a query string id then open a modal against the id. The modal open successfully but problem is the modal open twitch time. So Please suggest me how to prevent to open modal two times and ensure that the modal open only one time when query string has a id. My code is below:

```
myApp.controller('othersObjectiveListController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'EmployeeObjectiveService', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $uibModal, EmployeeObjectiveService, $routeParams) {

var items = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    items[i] = i;
}
$scope.test = items;



$scope.StatusBy = [{ id: 1, value: true, label: 'Approve' }, { id: 2, value: false, label: 'Pending' }];


//Angular Code for Multiple column show and hide

$scope.dropConfig = {
    scrollable: true,
    scrollableHeight: '340px',
    showCheckAll: false,
    showUncheckAll: false
}

EmployeeObjectiveService.getOtherObjectiveColumnList().then(function (response) { $scope.AllColumn = response.data });
EmployeeObjectiveService.getOtherSelectedColumn().then(function (response) { $scope.SelectedColumn = response.data });
EmployeeObjectiveService.getOtherObjectiveSelected().then(function (response) { $scope.SelectCol = response.data });


function changeColumnViewShow(item) {
    if (item.id == 1) {
        $scope.SelectCol.EmployeeID = !$scope.SelectCol.EmployeeID;
    } else if (item.id == 2) {
        $scope.SelectCol.EmployeeName = !$scope.SelectCol.EmployeeName;
    } else if (item.id == 3) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Code = !$scope.SelectCol.Code;
    } else if (item.id == 4) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Title = !$scope.SelectCol.Title;
    } else if (item.id == 5) {
        $scope.SelectCol.KPI = !$scope.SelectCol.KPI;
    } else if (item.id == 6) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Target = !$scope.SelectCol.Target;
    } else if (item.id == 7) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Weight = !$scope.SelectCol.Weight;
    } else if (item.id == 8) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Note = !$scope.SelectCol.Note;
    } else if (item.id == 9) {
        $scope.SelectCol.Status = !$scope.SelectCol.Status;
    }
}

$scope.changeEvents = {
    onItemSelect: function (item) {
        changeColumnViewShow(item);
    },
    onItemDeselect: function (item) {
        changeColumnViewShow(item);
    }
};
//End Column hide show function


// This Section for Pagination for Pending List
$scope.ViewItems = [{ value: 10, id: 10 }, { value: 20, id: 20 }, { value: 50, id: 50 }, { value: 100, id: 100 }];
$scope.selectItem = $scope.ViewItems[0];
$scope.ViewPerPage = 10;
$scope.setitemsPerPage = function (num) {
    $scope.ViewPerPage = num.value;
}

//This Section for Modal
$scope.viewObjectives = function (data) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/View/Modal View/OtherObjective.html',
        scope: $scope,
        size: 'lg',
    });
}

function ViewObjective($uibModalInstance, code) {
    $scope.id = code;
}

$scope.initial = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    if(id!=null)
    $scope.viewObjectives(id);
}

$scope.initial();


//PDF Create

$scope.CreatePDF = function () {
    $('#objectivelist').tableExport({
        type: 'pdf',
        fileName: 'ObjectiveList',
        jspdf: {
            orientation: 'l',
            format: 'a4',
            margins: { left: 10, right: 10, top: 20, bottom: 20 },
            autotable: {
                styles: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fillColor: 'inherit',
                    textColor: 'inherit'
                },
                tableWidth: 'auto'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}])

Comment: Is `viewObjectives` called from the mark-up at all?

Comment: share your html code too.

Comment: Thanks Yatrix . Its working